# python flask redirect to https from http

Tags: python, ssl, flask

I have a website build using python3.4 and flask...I have generated my own self-signed certificate and I am currently testing my website through localhost.

I am using the python ssl module along with this flask extension: https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify

```
context = ('my-cert.pem', 'my-key.pem')
app = Flask(__name__)
sslify = SSLify(app)

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = False
    app.run(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=int("5000"),
    ssl_context=context
)
```

This does not seem to be working however. I took a look in the sslify source code and this line does not seem to be working

```
def init_app(self, app):
    """Configures the configured Flask app to enforce SSL."""
    app.before_request(self.redirect_to_ssl)
    app.after_request(self.set_hsts_header)
```

Specifically the function call to redirect_to_ssl (I added my own print statement under the redirect_to_ssl function and my statement was never printed)

```
def redirect_to_ssl(self):
    print("THIS IS WORKING")
    """Redirect incoming requests to HTTPS."""
    Should we redirect?
    criteria = [
        request.is_secure,
        current_app.debug,
        request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto', 'http') == 'https'
    ]

    if not any(criteria) and not self.skip:
        if request.url.startswith('http://'):
            url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
            code = 302
            if self.permanent:
                code = 301
            r = redirect(url, code=code)
            return r
```

I am pretty new to python. Any ideas?

Answer (score 59):

To me, it appears you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. Here is the code I use in my views.py script to force user to HTTPS connections:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if not request.is_secure:
        url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
        code = 301
        return redirect(url, code=code)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it would redirect more than once, unless you have something else that's redirecting from https back to http somewhere, creating a loop. It should only redirect once.

Comment: Reason that @HimanshuMishra ran into issues that they are probably terminating SSL. Checking `request.is_secure()` is what you want because it respects the `X-Forwarded-Protocol` header. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14597

Comment: I think the change is as simple as: `if not request.is_secure():` as @tuned mentions below.

Comment: Should actually be request.is_secure

Comment: I did try this but if my app is running on port 443 (https), why would the flask app be listening at port 80 (http)?

Comment: @CamK I thought the same thing before, but now started using cloudfoundry and it is running a load balancer in front of my app (listening on HTTP and HTTPS), so I can't use my own SSL cert anymore since the balancer forwards all traffic to my app on HTTP

Comment: I ended up setting `request.scheme = 'https'`. This way `request.url` `request.base_url` etc. will each be updated.

Answer (score 19):

According with the [docs](https://github.com/heroku-python/flask-sslify), after `pip install Flask-SSLify` you only need to insert the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sslify import SSLify

app = Flask(__name__)
sslify = SSLify(app)
```

I have done it and it works very well. Am I missing something in the discussion ?

Comment: I believe flask_sslify is no longer maintained .. see @Eyal Levin 's answer below

Comment: Is "app.run" still required and do you specify a port?

Answer (score 19):

The [Flask Security Guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/security/#security-headers) recommends using [Flask-Talisman](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman).

```
$ pip install flask-talisman
```

Usage example:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_talisman import Talisman

app = Flask(__name__)
Talisman(app)
```

It forces `HTTPS` by default (from the README):

> `force_https`, default `True`, forces all non-debug connects to `https`.

---

Personally, I got some errors relating to CSP (Content Security Policy) which I disabled with:

```py
Talisman(app, content_security_policy=None)
```

But use this at your own risk :)

Comment: Also added `content_security_policy =None`. I tried GOOGLE_CSP_POLICY but it didn't work with google analytics. Also my "Twitter follow me" button wasn't working either. I didn't bother investigating more for something that was working as is before

Comment: What are the risks of using talisman?

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to answer from [Kelly Keller-Heikkila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5270172/kelly-keller-heikkila) and comment by [jaysqrd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1137353/jaysqrd) I ended up doing this in my Flask app:

```
from flask import request, redirect
...

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if app.env == "development":
        return
    if request.is_secure:
        return

    url = request.url.replace("http://", "https://", 1)
    code = 301
    return redirect(url, code=code)
```

I tried the `flask_sslify` solution suggested by [Rodolfo Alvarez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6262716/rodolfo-alvarez) but ran into [this issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify/issues/51) and went with the above solution instead.

If the app is running in development mode or the request is already on https there's no need to redirect.

Comment: I ended up setting `request.scheme = 'https'`. This way `request.url` `request.base_url` etc. will each be updated.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a flask solution if you are on aws and behind a load balancer.  Place it in your views.py

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    scheme = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto')
    if scheme and scheme == 'http' and request.url.startswith('http://'):
        url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
        code = 301
        return redirect(url, code=code)
```

Comment: this works for gcp app engine in flex env as well. Great job @edW

Comment: worked for me in cloudfoundry

Comment: If your request is already setting `X-Forwarded-Proto`, probably better to go with the official `ProxyFix` https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/middleware/proxy_fix/
like @mdubez's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The standard solution is to wrap the request with an `enforce_ssl` decorator that after checking some flags in the app configuration (flags you can set depending on your debugging needs) modifies the request's url with `request.url`.

As it is written [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/93/).

You can modify the code to make it working with `before_request` as suggested by @kelly-keller-heikkila

Answer (score 5):

I use a simple extra app that runs on port 80 and redirect people to https:

```
from flask import Flask,redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return redirect("https://example.com", code=302)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the other answers that I've been able to use with great success:

```
from http import HTTPStatus
from typing import Optional

from flask import Response, redirect, request, url_for


def https_redirect() -> Optional[Response]:
    if request.scheme == 'http':
        return redirect(url_for(request.endpoint,
                                _scheme='https',
                                _external=True),
                        HTTPStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT)


# ..

if app.env == 'production':
    app.before_request(https_redirect)

# ..
```

Answer (score 2):

On app engine flex, add:

```
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix

def create_app(config=None):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
```

In addition to the solution of:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if not request.is_secure:
        url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
        code = 301
        return redirect(url, code=code)
```

Otherwise it'll cause infinite redirects since SSL is unwrapped behind the proxy but is noted in the headers.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Using it with the following flags does not seem to need the before request patch:
`app = Flask(__name__); app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_host=1, x_proto=1)`

Comment: Just these lines - app = Flask(__name__); app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_host=1, x_proto=1) fixed the issue of 'Invalid Redirect URI' for me. App is behind AWS load balancer. Definitely this should be the accepted answer for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same solution running a Flask application in AWS Elastic Beanstalk behind a load balancer. The following AWS docs provided two steps to configure the environment for http redirects: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html Following both steps fixed my issue.

One thing to note is that you'll have to create the .ebextenions folder at the root level of your application source bundle and add the config file to that .ebextensions folder. The readme here: https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples explains this in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it seems, requests from a Private AWS API Gateway with a VPC endpoint don't include the "X-Forwarded-Proto" header.  This can break some of the other solutions (either it doesn't work or it continuously redirects to the same url).  The following middleware forces https on most flask generated internal redirects:

```
class ForceHttpsRedirects:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ["wsgi.url_scheme"] = "https"
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

# Usage
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ForceHttpsRedirects(app.wsgi_app) # Add middleware to force all redirects to https
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
app.run(port="443")
```

All modern browsers automatically use HTTPS when the port is 443 or 8443.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using cloud foundry python app which is behind a load balancer (like https://stackoverflow.com/users/5270172/kelly-keller-heikkila said) . 
This resolution helped me by adding (_external and _Scheme to the url_for function). https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/773

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and mine is a brute-force solution, but it works.
Heroku in the past suggested `flask_sslify`, which is not maintained anymore. Nowadays the proper way in Flask should be `flask-talisman`, but I tried it and it has bad interactions with boostrap templates.
I tried the anulaibar solution but it did not always worked for me.
The following is what I came up with:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    # If the request is sicure it should already be https, so no need to redirect
    if not request.is_secure:
        currentUrl = request.url
        if currentUrl.startswith('http://'):
            # http://example.com -> https://example.com
            # http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
            redirectUrl = currentUrl.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
        elif currentUrl.startswith('www'):
            # Here we redirect the case in which the user access the site without typing any http or https
            # www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
            redirectUrl = currentUrl.replace('www', 'https://www', 1)
        else:
            # I do not now when this may happen, just for safety
            redirectUrl = 'https://www.example.com'
        code = 301
        return redirect(redirectUrl, code=code)
```

I have the domain registered in godaddy which is also redirecting to https://www.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Flask app is sitting behind AWS API Gateway and solutions with @app.before_request were giving me permanent redirects.

The following simple solution finally worked:

```
@app.after_request
def adjust_response(response):
    ....
    if response.location:
        if app.env != "development":
            response.location = response.location.replace("http://", "https://", 1)
    return response
```

Comment: This is fixing the symptom, but not the underlying problem. You need to set up Flask to correctly handle headers in the proxy environment for security reasons. [Doing it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45333882/1749551) is actually less code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you expose the ports the flask in the logs shows what port it is running on?

it cannot serve http and https without their being a listener on both ports.

just run a container that redirects to the the https url serving on port 80 or 8080 depending on access. This is what brought me to this page to see if anyone else wanted to fix such a flask issue.