# how to redirect http to https in flask

Tags: python, flask, https, wsgi

I my Flask app to redirect http to https. I found
[python flask redirect to https from http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237379/python-flask-redirect-to-https-from-http) but it does not work.

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from werkzeug.serving import make_ssl_devcert


make_ssl_devcert('key')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if request.url.startswith('http://'):
        url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
        code = 301
        return redirect(url, code=code)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=443, debug=False, ssl_context=('key.crt', 'key.key'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this should better be done by `nginx` or whatever you are using in front of `flask`

For your question, you are listening only on the 443 port not the 80, which is the one http uses, so the http request does not actually hit your server.